# Drupal Taxonomy Google maps

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I am trying to make a list of places with taxonomy terms. Right now a I have a view that displays all of my terms but i want to add a "See on map" link for each terms that opens up google maps with the location of the selected place. Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try geotaxonomy module, where you can set lat/long for every taxonomy. I think to implement "See on map" functionality you mentioned, you need to get the lat/log from the taxonomy and write some code to show that location in the map.

http://drupal.org/project/geotaxonomy